# why isn't this removing (digit) each time it's run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var somestring = "mary(3) apple(2) sky(1)";
$("#removelaststring").unbind("click").bind("click",function(e){

somestring = somestring.replace(/\(\d+\)*$/, "")
alert(somestring);

});
```

i should get

```
mary(3) apple(2) sky
```

then if i run it agan

```
mary(3) apple sky
```

if run again

```
mary apple sky
```

however this doesn't happen, no matter how many times i click i get

```
mary(3) apple(2) sky
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an anchor ($) in your regex which requires it to match at the end of the string only. No characters after "(2)" are permitted.
I guess you want this

```
somestring = somestring.replace(/\(\d+\)([^(]*)$/, "$1")
```

allowing any characters but the '(' after the part that is removed. Assuming '(' is only going to appear as part of some "(2)".

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing '(n)' at the end of the string with '' (a blank string), so
`mary(3) apple(2) sky(1)` becomes `mary(3) apple(2) sky`, but then the next time around, there is not a '(n)' any more, so no further replacement takes place.